# How to place layout at the center of screen programmatically?

Tags: android-layout

layout1 is composed of status bar at the top and toolbar at the bottom of screen. And it is defined in xml.
I want to place layout2 between layout1's status bar and toolbar programmatically.

```
setContentView(R.layout.layout1);
layout2 = new MyLayout(this);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.leftMargin = 0;
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.statusbar); // this does not work.
addContentView(layout2, params);
```

This code puts layout2 at the top of screen so it hides layout1's status bar. How can I place layout2 at the location I want?
Is there other way not using addContentView?

Answer (score 2):

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
```

I tried this work.

Comment: I will try again. Then, how to place layout2 just below layout1's status bar? Let's assume status bar height is 100 pixels.

Comment: params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.statusbar) does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Set gravity in linear layout programmatically.

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
```

Comment: It does not work. It is the same. I think there is no way to do that using addContentView. Isn't there other way not using addContentView?

Comment: Try to use setLayoutParams in other layout.

Comment: I will try again. Then, how to place layout2 just below layout1's status bar? Let's assume status bar height is 100 pixels.

Comment: params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.statusbar) does not work.